# Extracting Company from Multi-tenant Shared Schema Database

Tags: sql-server-2014

We have a mutli-tenant shared schema database architecture. As a form of load distribution we have spread the tenants/companies across 6 SQL 2014 servers and 20 databases. All DBs are virtually the same except they hold about 10K different companies combined. We need the ability to extract entire companies out of one database and move them into another - some 200 tables. Ideally, we would like to be able to move them with minimal downtime. I am exploring ways to make this happen short of just writing custom scripts to copy every single table.

I learned you can setup replication with a filter based on a view (selectively extract company x data), but then I would have to setup replication for 200+ tables, which sounds cumbersome and could adverse impacts on production. Partitioning can do wonders, but not every table has a neat CompanyID reference. We don’t have AG but are planning on it and thought we could then use the replica to extract the company data as to not impact production.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for SSIS  and the Transfer SQL Server Objects Task https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141134(v=sql.120).aspx

Make sure you install and configure SSIS, and then you should be able to do this with ease.

Comment: Good tool, but it appears to only allow transfer of entire objects. In a multi-tenant structure, I only want to extract one company which may represent 2% of the data in any table.

Comment: Well, you can certainly use SSIS to copy a subset of the data over as well.
You'd probably want to create the table first in the new destination, but copying the data over is trivial with SSIS, even with some conditional logic.

Comment: Ok, I will look into this some more.